# Javascript Truthy / Falsy Operation

Tags: javascript, casting, truthiness

I have a question regarding javascript truthy / falsy

As far as I know, any non-zero number including negative numbers is truthy. But if this is the case then why

```
-1 == true //returns false
```

But also

```
-1 == false //returns false
```

Can someone shed some light? I would appreciate it.

Comment: "truthy" doesn't mean "equal to true", just like "positive" doesn't mean "equal to +1". There are lots of truthy values and `true` is just one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the `==` operator with a numeric operand and a boolean operand, the boolean operand is first converted to a number, and the result is compared with the numeric operand.  That makes your statements the equivalent of:

```
-1 == Number(true)
```

and

```
-1 == Number(false)
```

Which in turn are

```
-1 == 1
```

and

```
-1 == 0
```

Which shows why you're always seeing a `false` result.  If you force the conversion to happen to the numeric operand, you get the result you're after:

```
Boolean(-1) == true //true
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense when you explain it.

Answer (score 1):

No, a boolean is either 0 (false) or 1 (true) like a bit.

Here is an example:

```js
console.log(0 == false); // returns true => 0 is equivalent to false
console.log(1 == true); // returns true => 1 is equivalent to true
console.log(-1 == false); // returns false => -1 is not equivalent to false
console.log(-1 == true); // returns false => -1 is not equivalent to true
```

Answer (score 1):

Any non-zero number **evaluates** to true and zero **evaluates** to false.
That is not the same as being equal to true/false.

Executing the code here below (and substituting -1 with different values) could help you understand this:

```
if (-1) {
    true;
} else {
    false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the **@James Thorpe** answer, if you want to identify zero and non-zero numbers you can use the following code:

```js
console.log(Math.abs(-1) > 0);
console.log(Math.abs(0) > 0);
console.log(Math.abs(1) > 0);
```